# Where does Finder store data about favorite servers?

Tags: macos, finder

It used to store them under `~/Library/Recent Servers` but now I don't where it is.
My `~/Library/Favorites` contains only a `.localized` file with no data.

I am talking about Mac OS X 10.6.7.

I also reposted this question on [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15184157#15184157).

Answer (score 3):

There are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`. Open with Property List Editor (Xcode 3 Developer Tools) or Xcode 4 to view.

[image]

Comment: Daniel is correct. The file is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`
However, if you open the file in a text editor like TextWrangler, it'll be easier to edit and rearrange the list. Also, you must log out before the changes take effect.